# Room database is closed before migration

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I'm migrating and old sqlite db in app to Rooms and it works for 90% of users. The problem is it's not 100%.
According to crash reports devices have a lot of free space and RAM and most of them is Samsung Note 2 on Android 4.4. Also I'm not closing db anywhere in the app.

Crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.szyk.myheart/databases/database.db
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1648)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SourceFile:240)
       at com.szyk.myheart.data.room.Migrations$1.migrate(SourceFile:16)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(SourceFile:73)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(SourceFile:118)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:257)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(SourceFile:93)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SourceFile:54)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(SourceFile:305)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker$1.run(SourceFile:281)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

Room is initialised in Dagger module:

```
@Provides
@ApplicationScope
public static Database provideDatabase(Context context) {
    return Room
            .databaseBuilder(context, Database.class, "database.db")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .addMigrations(Migrations.MIGRATION_25_to_26)
            .addMigrations(Migrations.newDummyMigration(26, 27))
            .build();
}
```

Migration code:

```
public class Migrations {
    public static final Migration MIGRATION_25_to_26 = new Migration(25, 26) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            Timber.d("Migrating to room");
            Timber.d("Migration - creating new tables");
            // Create the new table - it fails on first call to db
            database.execSQL(
                    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_new (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, user_name TEXT NOT NULL, user_birth_date INTEGER, is_diabetes INTEGER NOT NULL)");
            ...

            Timber.d("Migration - completed");
        }
    };

    public static Migration newDummyMigration(int from, int to) {
        return new Migration(from, to) {
            @Override
            public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with migration itself. It crashed for the first time an exception was swallowed silently(Rx), then each next call executed migration on closed db.

Comment: Correct, the key point is that you only get the useful message *the first time*, and every other time you are given a closed db exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Entity where you made your changes. It needs to be the exact same as after the migration changes. Make sure you didn't forget to add any indexes, or properties to your entity.

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"name"})}, tableName = "mytable")
public class MyEntity  implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(collate = ColumnInfo.NOCASE)
    public String name;
```